# Javascript Regular Expression for a string that contains one or more of specified letters

Tags: javascript, sql, regex

I am using the following Regex to search the array of English words for all strings that contains letters C, A, L, I, R, E, T, N anywhere in the body of the string:

```
const regex = /\b(?=\w*C)(?=\w*A)(?=\w*L)(?=\w*I)(?=\w*R)(?=\w*E)(?=\w*T)(?=\w*N)\w+/ig;
```

Here is my JavaScript (https://jsfiddle.net/jarosciak/7tk4aL0h/) that demonstrates the above example when searching in an array of English words:
The script will successfully find the words:

```
CLARINET
```

This is a good start for me, but I really need the Regex expression that finds all the words (strings) that contains the most of the letters I specify:

So for example, if I specify the letters: X, C, L, A, R, I, N, E, T. 
It should find the word: CLARINET, even though I also specified the X as a one of the letters to search for.

I can do this in SQL without any issues, but I can't figure out how to do this in REGEX. Here is a working SQL example if that helps:

[image]

Comment: The value of `@regex` in your SQL already contains the regular expression you want. So, why don't you use that in your Javascript?

Comment: What *the most* in *the most of the letters* qualifies? Are you matching the regex against multiple input strings?

Comment: Hi @revo, actually I am after getting a single words that matches the most letters I specified in the regex query, however that's not likely something I can do. Albeit, thinking of it, the longest letter should probably be the most correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Regex will find only Carinet in sequence. Your question does not mention that if CLARINET will come in sequence or it will be in any order like CLRIATEN. But as per your data and my assumption that it will come in sequence, here you go. You can change the regex by adding /i for case insensitivity.

Regex: `'(CLARINET)+'`

If you think word can come anywhere in the text like some random data which contains all these words, you can use following.

Regex: `'[CLARINET]+'`

Comment: The first thing is clearly wrong as the OP wants to specify `XCLARINET` and still match `CLARINET`. Your approach can be improved, as currently your approach will also allow `fooCfoo` , as it is unanchored.

Comment: The second regex is likely the best thing I've got so far. I was able to amend my script to get the first and best word, containing the most characters I was searching for, it's here: https://jsfiddle.net/jarosciak/u3oy6zd0/

Comment: I am glad that it helped.